# Mask vs. Mode - Permissions

Tags: permissions

In simple form the what is the difference between "mask" and "mode"? From what I understand is if a file has a mask of `0755` the mode of the file would be `7022` correct? It is basically inverted numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files have *modes*, on creation time the *mask* will determine the mode, based on the requested mode. A mask works like a stencil and can best be illustrated using the binary representation.

An `umask` of `0002` (common octal integer format) is represented as

```
000 000 000 010
```

in binary form, or

```
--- --- --- -w-
```

in symbolic form.

Let's say a file is to be created by the user, the mode is `0777` by default (for executables), but the mask will be "substracted" in a manner of speaking. This results in the `w` bit to be removed.

```
--- rwx rwx rwx  (mode)
--- --- --- -w-  (mask)
_______________ -
--- rwx rwx r-x  ==  000 111 111 101  ==  0775
```

For regular files (non-executables), the requested mode is without the `x` (executable) bit, i.e. `0666`, so the mask will then result in:

```
--- rw- rw- rw-  (mode)
--- --- --- -w-  (mask)
_______________ -
--- rw- rw- r--  ==  000 110 110 100  ==  0664
```

The latter one is common in directory listings (in which the first octet with SUID/SGID bits isn't shown), e.g.:

```
-rw-rw-r--   2 gert gert      228 Mar 20  2012 .vimrc
```

Of course, you can always change these modes with for example the `chmod` command, for which the umask will not be considered in editing.